# On the construction "être / y avoir / rester + à + infinitive"

Tags: verbes

> Pourquoi donc, demanda Bovary, ce seigneur **est**-il **à** la
>   **persécuter**?

(*Madame Bovary*, Deuxième partie, Chapitre XV)

I know that this construction, ***être* / *y avoir* / *rester* + à + infinitive**, has in English a passive *entendre*, e.g., *Cette voiture **est à nettoyer***, meaning *This car **is to be cleaned (up)***.

But in the line from *Madame Bovary*, the "intrusion" of the pronoun *la* seems to make this passive sense hardly intelligible. Without it, *[...] ce seigneur est-il à persécuter ?* would clearly have been *[...] is this gentleman to be persecuted?*

But with *la* stuck in there, I don't know if it's the same construction Flaubert used. And I also don't know how I am to render into English the whole thing: *ce seigneur est-il à la persécuter ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ce seigneur est à la persécuter.

is just a more literary way to say:

> Ce seigneur est en train de la persécuter.

We find in Grevisse that *être en train de, être à, être après à* (this last one is outdated) are used to show the action is in progress.

> Être en train de, être à, être après à* (ce dernier tour est vieilli) servent à marquer l'aspect duratif de l'action :
>
> - Il est **en train de** se ruiner (Ac.). — Elle **est à** s'habiller. — Il **est après à** bâtir sa maison (Ac.). (*Le bon usage*, §655 4°, 10<sup>e</sup> édition)

- Elle est à s'habiller.
- Elle est en train de s'habiller.

Both mean "she's getting dressed".

The BDL though advises against using *être à* and *être après* to talk about an action in progress.

> Les locutions verbales *être à* et *être après* ne doivent pas être employées pour parler d’une action en cours d’exécution. Il faut plutôt dire être en train de suivi du verbe à l’infinitif. [Être à et être après](http://%C3%8Atre%20%C3%A0%20et%20%C3%AAtre%20apr%C3%A8s)

Comment: I'm curious to know what's the exact phrasing in Grevisse.